# Caliburn Micro MVVM Services

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I have 2 services, `AService` and `BService`.

`AService` contains an observable collection of X.

`BService` needs to be able to access this property.

ATM, I'm passing in the collection to a function in `BService` from a view model that has `AService` injected into it via its constructor.

Is there a better way to do this?

I know you can't inject a service into another service so that went out the window.

Comment: Can't you use the simple ioc container to provide the same instance of these services to anything requires them?

Comment: I'm talking about a service that needs a collection contained in another service, does that make sense?

Comment: Why can't you inject one service into another? If these are just classes then you add aservice to the ctor of b and the instance will be passed in. If not in caliburn then use a better ioc container.

Comment: Thing is our entire system is now using caliburn micro for di construction so it's hard to switch from it now. The construction in caliburn micro is more you give it the interface and the concrete class to create it from, then you can inject that interface anywhere

Comment: From a quick glance at the docs. DimpleIOC seems to support the usual IOC constructor injection. When you register a dependency that will be resolved. Including when a class you're resolving has that dependency. Read constructor injection https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/simple-container  And think of Aservice as being a dependency for BService. That you can inject using constructor injection.

Comment: Thanks Andy I'll give it a read. This DI caliburn micro stuff can be a bit heavy for me but I've been slowly digesting it. Thanks for the pointer :)

Answer (score 1):

I think your basic assumption that services dependencies will not be resolved is incorrect.
From here:

https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/simple-container

Quote:

**Injecting Services**
The main benefit of Dependency injection is that any service requested will have it’s dependencies resolved before it is returned to the caller. **This is recursive so dependencies are satisfied for the whole object graph returned.** This process can also be utilized on instances that did not originate from the dependency container in the form of property injection.
Constructor Injection
Constructor injection is the most widely used form of dependency injection and it denotes a required dependency between services and the class into which they are injected. Constructor injection should be used when you require the non optional use of a given service.

```
public class ShellViewModel {
    private readonly IWindowManager _windowManager;
    
    public ShellViewModel(IWindowManager windowManager) {
        _windowManager = windowManager;
    }
}
```

By specifying IWindowManager as a constructor parameter we are explicitly requesting it as a non optional service. If ShellViewModel gets constructed by the dependency container it will have an implementation of IWindowManager injected into it.

In short.

If you add a parameter to BService that is an AService then ioc will resolve Aservice so long as you registered it.